# IsCancellationRequested is always false if CancellationTokenSource with delay

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource

I try to stop process by CancellationToken with timer.

But IsCancellationRequested  is always false.

I tried to call `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` it doesn't work.

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<ISearchableDevice>> SearchAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100, cancellationToken);
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // doesn't work
    }

    IReadOnlyList<ISearchableDevice> devices = new List<ISearchableDevice>();
    return devices;
}

private void OnStartSearchCommandExecuted(object? p)
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
    {
        try
        {  
             InProgress = true;
             DeviceSearcher.SearchAsync(cts.Token)
                 .ContinueWith(task =>
                 {
                  InProgress = false;

                 }, cts.Token);
         }                
         catch (Exception)
         {
                    // TODO: Add exception handling
         }
    }           
}
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: try to use `await` in the `SearchAsync` call instead of `ContinueWith`. For now your `cts` is disposed before it reach timeout.

Comment: @Serg I think you are right, But I should use async void, because my commands are not async

Comment: @Serg You were right. Thank you. You can fill out the answer

Comment: "But I should use async void, because" - there are remarkably few correct ways of ending that sentence. Almost any time you type "async void", you're creating a problem.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I know. I should write async command

Comment: @MarcGravell or change my code logic

Comment: @MarcGravell: because the async function never returns.

Comment: @Joshua that changes nothing

Comment: @Joshua It never returns (in the happy case). There, I corrected it for you. What Marc is alluding to is that the function can throw an exception, in that case, async void will not have a stack to bubble the exception up through. This means, there is no where for the program to go except out of main.

Comment: @Aron: I wrote one that looked like this: `async void BackgroundJob() { for(;;) { try { await Task.Delay(360000); var h = new HttpClinet(); var str = await h.GetStringAsync("..."); /* do something with str*/ } catch (WebException e) { /* server down try again later */ } catch (Exception e) { /* log it */ } } }`

Comment: @Joshua, this case you don't have proper clean up if and when you use the cancellation token,  which,  sure you aren't using now.  But later,  you won't realise why it's not working...

Comment: @Aron: I can't come up with a situation where `async void SomeFunction(..., CancellationToken cancellationToken)` is correct either. I did have a place where I had to shut one of these down, but it was not done with a cancellation token, but by changing the configuration (in the containing class) to not runnable and let it shut itself down in a safe (actually meaning low recovery cost) spot.

Comment: @Joshua. The correct thing to do it use `protected abstract Task BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)`. When AspNetCore shuts down. It will cancel the ExecuteAsync with the CancellationToken, BUT it will also wait for the Task to complete/throw. You can simply use a try/finally to run clean up code, such as `BatchedLoggingShippingService.ShipLog` on a queue of batched logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240454/discussion-between-aron-and-joshua).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `cts` is disposed before timeout is reached. More precisely, it is disposed immediately after `SearchAsync` reaches first `await`.
You have at least two ways to solve this

1. Use `await DeviceSearcher.SearchAsync` instead of `DeviceSearcher.SearchAsync().ContinueWith()`. This is the best way, but it will force you to make the `OnStartSearchCommandExecuted` async.
2. Remove `using` block and call `Dispose` manually inside `.ContinueWith` (and move  other post-searh logic inside `ContinueWith` and also do not forget call `Dispose` in case of exceptions (whether exception will occur in synchronous part of SearchAsync (before first `await`) or in asynchronous part. )).

Comment: Generally speaking `Task.ContinueWith()` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Aron why is it a bad idea?

Comment: I think, I can use event. When search task cancelled I call event. In event handler method doing next work ( with dispatcher if need)

Comment: I will do it https://learn.microsoft.com/en/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-commands

Comment: Continue with breaks using blocks, try/catch/finally blocks, stack traces, SynchronizationContext (and hence WPF/WinForms/Blazor). These are just a few examples where things will just go wrong, rather than falling into the pit of success...

Comment: async/await does a lot of things that helps with fall into the pit of success that `Task.ContinueWith` does not do. For example, your try/catch is doing absolutely nothing in your example. Also, assuming WPF, ContinueWith will not marshell the call back to the Dispatcher, which can cause issues...